# What does $$ sign means in mysql?

Tags: mysql

In MySQL query, what does the $$ signify?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER before_population_update
BEFORE UPDATE ON City
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO City_Changes
SET ACTION = ‘update’,
CityID = OLD.ID,
Population = OLD.Population,
User = USER(),
ChangedOn = NOW();
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: mysql default delimiter is ; and your defining some other delimiter in above trigger definition $$

Comment: You are defining it as a delimiter in the first line. What do you think it means? It has no special meaning.

Comment: that will help you to paste all the text untill it $$ to execute in single block

Comment: i think this question should exist, but still be marked as a duplicate. if you didn't know that `$$` was a delimiter, you wouldn't know to search for that and instead search for the title of this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Triggers and stored procedures are [potentially] made up of several statements, which are each terminated by `;`. Since `;` is used to terminate an individual statement, they need a way to indicate the procedure/trigger is done - and this is where the `delimiter` command comes into play.

On the first row, we define the following trigger will be delimited (ended) by the `$$` sequence. We then go on to declare a trigger (starting with `create trigger` and ending with `$$` as we defined). Then, on the last row, we reset the `delimiter` to the default `;` for good measures.